# Using multipatch and surface in ArcGIS 3D Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, 3d-model, multipatch

I want to get 3D building. I have DEM surface and 3D feature of building roof. I created multipatch class by extruded building roof with '-' value.

Is it possible to create building from this multipatch and DEM surface ?

[image]

Interpolate Polygon To Multipatch (3D Analyst) create only footprnt of building's roof on TIN surface. Output is Multipatch but it is only plane. How can I create Multipatch between Roof's polygon and footprint's Multipatch ?
[image]

Comment: Interpolate Polygon To Multipatch (3D Analyst) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Interpolate_Polygon_To_Multipatch/00q90000004v000000/ Creates surface-conforming multipatch features from a polygon feature class using a raster, terrain, or TIN surface

Comment: How do you want to use the 3D building?

Comment: i want to create some shadow map